# AND condition for struts logic:emprty tag

Tags: java, struts

How to add a AND condition for struts, for example both a and b is empty do something?

```
<logic:empty name="a">
//do something                                      
</logic:empty>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, this may help

```
<logic:empty name="a">
   <logic:empty name="b">
    //do something        
    </logic:empty>                             
</logic:empty>
```

Comment: `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>` 

Remember to add dependencies (at the top of the page).

Answer (score 1):

This is limitations of the  tags. There is no easy way to do an **and** or **or** condition. I'd advise you to use JSTL:

```
<c:if test="${a == 1 && b == 1}"> Your code here </c:if>
```

You can change comparision logic according to your property

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<c:if test="${(empty a)  && (empty b)}">
//do something 
</c:if>
```